# What is the recommended way to improve question writing without being downvoted into oblivion?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality

I've posted a question that received a downvote. The original downvoter didn't specify an issue with the question. Luckily, a senior user (@kapa) helped me to identify some issues with it, and I've edited it twice in hopes of clarifying the question in order to be more specific.

I read the post on "How to Ask" and a few of the discussions regarding bad questions. Are there some other things I can do to improve my question writing? How can we tell if our question is of good quality but poorly formed versus a question that is not likely to be answered due to the subject matter or other factors? Are there some senior users that would be willing to give advice to new users on how to participate on Stack Overflow without being a nuisance? (I'd like to contribute, but not if I will do more harm than good!)

Would it be possible to have a separate section for "beginners", so we can make some mistakes and have guidance? It seems that Stack Overflow is undergoing a period of intense editing and clean-up, which is fantastic, but it will be difficult to improve as a new user without more feedback and constructive criticism.

This is the question: [Why is merging Python system classes with custom classes less desirable than hooking the import mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23766252/1989418)

*I found [this quote from Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/) that sums up my experience over the past three days with Stack Overflow.*

> Yes, by God, we will trick you into becoming a better writer if that's
>   what it takes – and it always does. Stack Overflow has many overtly
>   gamelike elements, but it is a game in service of the greater good –
>   to make the internet better, and more importantly, to make you better.
>   Seeing my fellow programmers naturally improve their written
>   communication skills while participating in a focused, expert Q&A
>   community with their peers? Nothing makes me prouder.

*It did feel like a game (a game I was losing), however with some hard work and effective help from everyone, I've been tricked into becoming a better writer by practice, out in the open for all to see. It's difficult having your process of improvement shown to everyone, as we'd all like to write the perfect question in one go. I'd liken it to learning a musical instrument because ultimately we all share in that experience. It's been very rewarding!*

Comment: delete it temporarily to prevent further downvotes, then edit it up to standards and undelete it.

Comment: @me how - That's a great suggestion - I hadn't thought of this. Thanks!

Comment: @Amal Murali: NOOOO YOU'RE JUST GONNA INVOKE THE META EFFECT

Comment: "It seems that SO is undergoing a period of intense editing and clean-up" Yeah, which it's been in since the site first opened...  SO, unlike pretty much every other programming Q/A site, demands a high standard of quality for questions and answers.  It was one of the guiding principles of the creation of the site.

Comment: There's an entire help center just *full* of information on how to ask good questions, with plenty of links to additional resources for further information.  You can also spend time reading through other questions to see what types of questions are well/poorly received on the site to learn from others before asking your own questions.  If you actually want to ask a good question, there's more than enough information out there on how to do it well.

Comment: Since you're asking in that question for elaboration on another answer, it might be more appropriate to have posted a comment on the original answer asking for elaboration (instead of a new question). The author of the original answer is in the best position to explain what they meant.

Comment: @Andrew Medico - I don't have enough reputation points to post a comment. I would have preferred to post a comment, rather than asking a question. Thanks for your suggestion, I will do that…eventually!

Comment: Surprising that you didn't get more downvotes, that 1st version was incredibly unclear.  Just ask a co-worker to read it first, you would have gotten a pretty quick "dude, what are you talking about?" comment before exposing it to the world.

Comment: @Servy - I intend to spend more time on researching how to ask good questions (which is my purpose in posing this question). The confusing thing is that I posted a question previously which received quite good feedback, and I'm not clear on the differences between the two. I think the specificity of the question sometimes obfuscates the advice. But I'll keep working on it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @HansPassant - You're right, it was quite vague as I'm realizing now, and far too wordy. I won't make that mistake again!

Comment: I asked a general question about [newbie-ness](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254881/the-many-shades-of-newbie-ness) and got reminded of [this great piece](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S. Raymond. Written way before SO, but still the best guide to asking a question on the internet.

Comment: related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: I think it should be a common sense to politely point out why you down-voted something. Because if you are doing that to an answer it points out that there is something wrong with it, if someone read it and wasn't certain they would probably want to know why it is wrong. The same thing is with questions, other people then the author will probably read it in the feature, very likely because they wanted to ask something similar, and comments should help them not to make same mistakes if and when they ask.

Comment: @PSIXO It's additionally hard because new users are restricted from commenting, so you have to start out by asking a question which can be very tough! I keep thinking it's a sociological experiment and game-like process that forces us to level-up or give-up. I'm sure a lot of thought was put in to allow it to function like this though. I don't play video or board games, nor do the majority of my coder friends, so perhaps it can be a bit limiting in that sense. I'm assuming that in a game, you don't receive a lot of feedback on how to play it correctly?

Comment: @jspacek I totally agree with the problem of commenting restriction when beginning but then again without enough reputation they can't down vote.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that there are too many words.  And it seems awfully broad.  A question should address one specific issue.

Comment: By the say, receiving ONE downvote is almost a complement.  I've had questions receive 10 or more.  I suspect you're being a little over-sensitive.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, I wouldn't admit to that... but I do like to improve and respond constructively to criticism. I suppose a downvote is a sign that someone took the time to evaluate the question! I'm sure that as you become familiar with the 'game' it's less of an issue. Difficult for first-timers.

The question was research-based, so it was broad in the beginning but reformatting it for SO Q&A format helped me to outline some tasks!

Comment: @jspacek - It does seem to be a "game" to some people, and in many cases one that they believe they can "win" only by making others lose.  This is unfortunate, but it's what it is.

Comment: Biggest thing--don't let downvotes bother you, consider them a learning experience at worst and a badge of honor at best :)  Generally if you have a well-meaning, reasonably phrased question, downvotes will provide you with a net +rep since people will tend to counter a -1 or -2 with a + vote if they think you are sincere.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've read the [original revision of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23766252/1) and these are some things I noticed:

- There was **no question** anywhere. You just described some facts and finally said "Any recommendations would be welcome".
- It was **unclear** what was being asked. I, for one, couldn't understand what was being asked in the question. It was not clear whether you were looking for help with a specific issue, or just a guidance in general or something else.
- It was a bit **too broad**. I am not familiar with Python, but from a quick read, your question appeared a little broad to me:

  > The solution to merge functions, rather than relying on the import mechanisms, seems to be the best approach in my case. My interpositioning mechanism should be rather transparent, and not rely on any underlying environment setting, such as PYTHONPATH or namespaces. It should not be fragile, and hopefully work with subsequent versions of Python. It should also not try to merge the functions each time it is run.

  Someone reading this might interpret it as a code-request, which is frowned upon.

With your edit, the question has improved a lot. If you receive a comment from someone else,  perhaps edit the question to improve it further. Or you can temporarily delete the question, improve it and *then* undelete it.

---

> Would it be possible to have a separate section for "beginners", so we can make some mistakes and have guidance?

No, that sounds like a very bad idea. This could lead to total chaos — a site where newbies ask totally stupid questions about syntax errors and such and another ones where experts lurk. I don't think that's going to work.

> It seems that SO is undergoing a period of intense editing and clean-up

It is and has always been. Stack Overflow is a community-moderated website and edits/closings etc. are what helps this site maintain its quality.

> it will be difficult to improve as a new user without more feedback and constructive criticism.

Not really. A lot of downvoters explain their reasoning in the comments. Don't take downvotes too personally. If you receive a downvote and wonder what's wrong with your question, you might consider leaving a comment asking for explanation. Make sure to do it in a constructive manner. Something like "why da downvotez pls explain" is likely to do more harm than good.

Comment: this is really great feedback! Thank you so much for your time in spelling these things out. I had guessed at some of the issues, and went with my gut with the edits hoping for the best. Now I'm wondering what is wrong with this current question - as it has just received a down vote.

Comment: @AmalMurali - this is a question for me, I think? Yes, I (she), wasn't sure if it is appropriate to link it, as it could be perceived as hounding people for up votes on the original question. I can edit the question to include the link, if it is helpful.

Comment: @jspacek: It helps to include the link to the question as it gives more context and have more idea about the situation. Without seeing the question, it wouldn't be possible to give specific suggestions. Anyway, interested people can always find it on your Stack Overflow profile and I don't see the need to have it in here. You can edit it in if you'd like — I don't see any issues with it. People do it all the time. (Note that it will attract more attention if this Meta post becomes popular. Be prepared to deal with that in case.) :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I've edited the question to include the link at the end. Re-reading your answer, I've realized that my question originally did sound like a Christmas wish list of requested code, where I thought I was explaining the requirements fully. Which is silly, because I myself do not enjoy reading through documentation and much prefer to have concise explanation.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I hadn't realized this, but it makes sense to down vote in disagreement as well as to indicate that there are issues in the question (hence the 'vote' terminology).

Comment: It was difficult to choose the accepted answer because I found all of the answers to be very helpful in different ways. I chose this answer because I believe it will be useful generally for anyone else who comes across this question in the future.

Answer (score 19):

One other thing lacking from your original question is, "I've already tried the following, and instead of getting what I wanted, I got the following result instead."

This is an enormously important part of most good questions. When you add this bit, you tell the possible answerers a lot. First off, somebody who sees the effort you've already made to solve your own problem is much more likely to make some effort to share a possible solution with you.

Second, it steers people away from offering you a solution that you have already found to be bad.

Third, it sometimes clarifies your original intent, in case that wasn't clear in your problem statement.

In your question, you mention what might be the best approach, but you don't say whether you have tried it out (even in a prototype) or, if not, why not.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't apparent that I already implemented the import mechanism solution, and that we wanted to try out a more long term solution. Since I'm working on a research project, we have a greater luxury of time compared to what I've experienced working in the private sector. I believe this is why my earlier question from 2 years ago was naturally better suited for the Q&A format. I think my Python research question is clearer now in the updated version, but please let me know if it could use further refinement.

Comment: +1 And it shows effort of solving the problem which instantly makes your question above many that include "searched alotfoundnothing" as demonstration of serious effort.

Answer (score 11):

It happens you ask a question in a rush and then realize you either shouldn't have asked it or the way you worded it wasn't really great... what to do to avoid downvotes and closure?

If you are getting downvotes on your question, there is probably something wrong with it already, it's either poor quality, unclear or does not show any research. (*hover over the downvote tip*)

When you notice downvotes or close votes; stop there and delete your question temporarily.

[Make sure your question is an actual question which in this context means it is within the scope of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
In addition to what you already know which is [what is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page there is also a better guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It thoroughly explains what a good question is. It's definitely worth reading if you are a beginner and planning on asking many questions.

**Before you ask or after you have temporaily deleted your question**

Firstly, make sure your question is not a duplicate. You can only find out if it's not by searching for the problem you have. If you do find something similar but not exactly the same, save reference to it. Demonstrate in your question that you have been researching and searching and possibly provide a link explaining why and how your problem is different and why the linked post didn't help you resolve your issue.

Secondly, once you realize your question is unique and has not been asked before you start editing your original question. Start by explaining what you are doing. Not in a sentence. Explain it like if you were telling someone who just walking in to a room and does not have a clue what you are doing/talking about. Make sure others can actually understand where you're coming from and how you've arrived at the problem.

Then, describe where the problem is. What is that you do and don't understand about it. What are you expected results and what are the results you are getting. Tell us what you have tried to resolve your issue. Demonstrate what you actually have tried, and why it didn't work - it's important for a reader of you question to know what you have already tried. Not all questions are as obvious to answer as what is 1 + 1. Some questions require the answerer to do research on his own, providing details of what you have tried already saves valuable (*and free - not paid for*) time of the professional who will be helping you.

If you have links to external resources make sure you don't just say `http://example.com` where there are tons of pages and data - point to the right resource and explain where and how to find information related to your problem.

Remove any "Thanks in advance" and anything else that is causing chaos and is not related to your problem. We say thanks by upvoting and accepting answers which are helpful to us.

Re-read your question as if you were someone else. Is it understandable? Does it make sense? Have you clearly described what you are doing and how you arrived at the problem? Have you shown your research and attempts at solving your problem?

If you can put a check mark at the above questions then I assure you, you are good to go and either ask/undelete your question. There shouldn't be any(*further*) downvotes and if there are possibly consider bringing it to meta and asking for further support.

Comment: this is a very specific answer and it is helping me to see the culture of SO a bit better. I always put extraneous details like "thanks so much, in advance, etc.". I will keep this in check - as a Canadian, it is difficult not to begin with "Sorry". I will up vote instead!