# Should I delete my question if it got negative votes?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recognize the flaws in my question, but still (to my knowledge) there wasn't anything similar enough on Stack Overflow to it, and I think it could still help others.

However it got negative votes (-2), so maybe I'm wrong and overly optimistic with the usefulness-to-others of this question.

Should I delete it?

Comment: If anything, you should fix the question if you know it's flawed.

Comment: That's right! I added a second part to try and fix the flaw that I saw and felt was largest (too narrow perspective). The other problem I had was I was stumped even after reading up on it that I couldn't even put my attempts in because they were dismal!

Comment: Can you post a link to your question? An actual example makes the discussion more concrete. "(too narrow perspective)" could mean anything to me.

Comment: If it's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851608/complete-partially-filled-in-columns-based-on-established-relationships-between) it's currently +9/-2, so I'd say that the community has voted that the question is, in fact, just fine. I say leave it.

Comment: Well, if you think your question/answer can help someone new to the subject, don't delete it, even though it gets down votes from experts. after all we are not here to improve tally of our reputation but to learn and help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the recommended way to improve question writing without being downvoted into oblivion?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255680/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-improve-question-writing-without-being-downvoted)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the question is possibly useful, don't delete it. If the answers are useful, don't delete it. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851608/complete-partially-filled-in-columns-based-on-established-relationships-between) is not worth deleting because it has a good answer (and it's a fine question after the edits).

Comment: Agreed; and I think the edited question isn't bad.

Comment: Also, you can be blocked from asking questions if you delete too many of your questions that have negative votes.

Comment: +1 to Dubstaphone. To add to his point, the ban on asking questions is for unknown period of time. It could be in months. I think it depends on reputation.

Comment: Heh, from a distance, I didn't see that "this question" was a link, and I thought you were promoting this question and your answer. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't delete questions which have at least one answer as described in this answer

Comment: What if you don't know why it was downvoted (no comment explaining why), and the question seems good to you, but you don't want the ding on your reputation?

Answer (score 2):

If the answer is opinion-based (which it seems to me to be - tell me if I'm wrong), here's mine:

I think if there's no end to the negative votes in sight (and you've already tried editing it a few times), it would be a good idea to delete the question, unless you don't care about your reputation points. If the negative votes stop, then by all means, keep it up.

Also, it should be noted that you might gain the peer pressure badge if you do delete it. So, if you want that, that's a reason. If you don't want it, avoid deleting it.

Anyway, those are the selfish reasons to consider.

If you want to help others at any cost, just don't delete it. Or, you could delete (or edit) it and ask a more likable question that helps the same people the same amount or better.

Also, you could always delete it and then ask the same question on something like the Ubuntu Forums' programming talk forum. Then, at least people will be able to find it on Google, and you won't be penalized for it.

Edit: Dubstaphone makes a fine point in the comments to another answer. That seems to indicate that maybe it isn't opinion-based. Check that out before you decide to delete anything. Maybe we're just not supposed to delete stuff because of downvotes. The fact remains, however, that sometimes people still downvote without explanation even after you've edited for clarification more than once (although this isn't a terribly frequent occurrence, in my experience, unless you like to ask questions that are perfectly valid, but seem ridiculous).