# Cannot delete my old post (I want to ask a new question with updated code and logcat file)

Tags: discussion, support

After going through the post *[Should I delete my answer if it gets negative votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256631/should-i-delete-my-answer-if-it-gets-negative-votes)*, I still want to delete [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255893/getting-object-value-instead-of-the-complete-file) as it is containing older code and ask a new question instead as it would not make any sense (to edit this post itself and ask the new question in this old post). So isn't it wise to delete it and ask a new question?

When I delete the post it shows me the below pop-up.

[image]

Also if I do not delete this post then when I ask a question I would possibly get a marked as duplicate on my post (with the duplicate pointing to my previous question).

Comment: If the answers to the old Q don't answer your new one, then it's probably not a dup.  I'd say leave the old one, post your new one and include a link and explanation why it's not a dup

Comment: Its what I have tried @chrisneilsen I updated the whole code along with my output explaining the changes then expected  for an answer but got only negative marking which blocked me from asking any question.Least bothered about the rep coz I know my question is valid but I am also bothered for the answer.

Comment: That's _not_ what you tried.  You actually did what I advised not to do.

Comment: ok let's give a try for that also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, as you have been notified by the system, it is not possible to delete a question that has an answer. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) explains in detail how and when questions can actually be deleted, while [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow) is exactly like the one you asked.

After taking a quick look at [your questions revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24255893/revisions), specially revisions 4 and 5, I must say that I do not approve what you have done. You did change the question in any possible way, and made the answers useless yourself.

You should consider to roll back to roll-back to revision 3 of the question.

In the future, if a question is answered, and a new one bothers you that is actually related, do as chris neilsen said and as a new question with possibly a link to the answered one as background.

EDIT: Carl Veazey did the roll-back for you.